# i created this code which is working fine if kept in header but not working in functions php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

```
if ( !function_exists('nopaymentmade') ) {
    function nopaymentmade( $user_id ){

        global $wpdb;
        //print_r($wpdb);

        $listing_accounts_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ht_listing_accounts';
        //$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_ht_listing_accounts WHERE account_type=paid-membership " );
        //print_r($myrows);

        $today =date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_ht_listing_accounts WHERE DATEDIFF(end_date,curdate())<=15 AND account_type='paid-membership'") as $key => $row) {

            // each column in your row will be accessible like this
            $userid = $row->user_id;

            //echo DATEDIFF($row->end_date,date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID=$userid ") as $key1 => $row1) {

                $row1->user_email;
                //$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
                echo $user_login = stripslashes( $row1->user_login );
                echo $user_email = stripslashes( $row1->user_email );

                //$message  = sprintf( __('New user registration on %s:'), get_option('blogname') ) . "\r\n\r\n";
                //$message .= sprintf( __('Username: %s'), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
                //$message .= sprintf( __('E-mail: %s'), $user_email ) . "\r\n";

                $message="User id in your website IIHF has expired at IIHF.ie. Please ask your user to renew it Immediately. A user with the username:".$user_login."and email id :".$user_email."";

                @wp_mail(
                    'singh.manjot007@gmail.com',
                    sprintf(__('[%s] Hello admin a User is Expiring'), get_option('blogname') ),
                    $message
                );


                /*$message  = __('Hi there,') . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf( __("Welcome to %s! Here's how to log in:"), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf( __('Username: %s'), $user_login ) . "\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf( __('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass ) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf( __('If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option('admin_email') ) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= __('Adios!');*/

                $message1="Your Account User id has expired at IIHF.ie. Please renew it Immediately. Please contact the site administrator for the Support";


                wp_mail(
                    $user_email,
                    sprintf( __('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname') ),
                    $message1
                );
                mail($user_email,'Your registration is expiring',$message1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the function i have created which works fine as it is created to send a email to admin and user when any user registration end date is coming close within 15 days then it sends a email to both of them informing them that their registration is expiring. Problem is tht if i keep this code in header.php it sends a email again and again every time when page gets refreshed so i created and function and add the code inside a function in functions.php in wordpress but it is not working then. Please tell me what to do and help me on this.

Comment: okay i did this add_action('wp_head', 'nopaymentmade'); but problem is that it keeps sending the email everytime page refreshes and function is getting called on... what should i do to avoid it –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I am Answering the question as I Searched a lot through functions and wordpress codex. and Finally i found out the solution to my question. I thought that i should share it. Now I have done this and now my function only run once in a day. I have added a hook to wordpress for it. Please check in my answer.

```
            //add_action('user_register', 'nopaymentmade');
            add_action( 'prefix_daily_event', 'nopaymentmade' );

            add_action( 'wp', 'prefix_setup_schedule' );
            /**
             * On an early action hook, check if the hook is scheduled - if not, schedule it.
             */
            function prefix_setup_schedule() {
                if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'prefix_daily_event' ) ) {
                    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'prefix_daily_event');
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

call this function in function.php with wp_head() hook. I hope that will help for you.

Comment: how to use that wp_head() hook can you please alter my answer to show me that

Comment: okay i did this add_action('wp_head', 'nopaymentmade'); but problem is that it keeps sending the email everytime page refreshes and function is getting called on... what should i do to avoid it

Comment: ok, you can use user_register() hook for this. This call when user register on website.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register   I  hope this link help you

Comment: Hello chandni . Thanks for your help but it was not what i was searching. I however have posted the answer. If you get the time please do check it. Thanks.

Comment: This is a great solution. Good job :)